# Unable to rewrite PATH when setting Rtools

Tags: r, windows, path

In my windows 10, the directory of Rtools cannot be correctly set. My rtools is installed in D drive (D:/Rtools) and I've done these:

1. I manually set the PATH in the `Environmental Variables...`: 
   [screenshot for PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHFgf.png)
2. I changed the `Makeconf`: `BINPREF ?= D:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/`

However, everytime restarting R, I get an Rtool path directing to C drive (`C:\\Rtools\\bin;`):

```r
Sys.getenv("PATH")
#> [1] "C:\\Rtools\\bin;D:\\R\\R-stable\\bin\\x64;d:\\Rtools\\bin;d:\\Rtools\\mingw_64\\bin;d:\\Rtools\\mingw_32\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;D:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;D:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;D:\\qpdf-6.0.0\\bin;D:\\qpdf-6.0.0\\lib;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Seagate\\SnapAPI\\;D:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinMerge;d:\\Rtools\\bin;d:\\Rtools\\mingw_64\\bin;D:\\Ruby24-x64\\bin;D:\\Ruby25-x64\\bin;C:\\Users\\Yue Hu_local\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;"
```

Everything else looks fine and R seems able to find the rtools and relevants, while the packages cannot be compiled successfully from the source:

```r
devtools::find_rtools()
#> [1] TRUE
Sys.which("ls.exe")
#>                    ls.exe 
#> "d:\\Rtools\\bin\\ls.exe"
Sys.which("gcc.exe")
#>                              gcc.exe 
#> "d:\\Rtools\\mingw_64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
```

Comment: There are system and user environmental variables.  You could check to see if the path is set in whichever one you didn't look at previously.

Comment: How did you start R?  Besides what Dason mentioned about user and system variables, whatever program runs R sets the environment variables that it sees.  If you are using RStudio, then it may causing the problem.

Comment: @Dason, thank you for the suggestion. However, I tried to add the correct rtools path to both system and user environmental variables. That did not change anything. Also, what I am most confused now is where the "C:\\Rtools\\bin;" comes from---I didn't specify it anywhere.

Comment: @user2554330, I tried to start R from both the built-in GUI and Rstudio. `Sys.getenv("PATH")` returns the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the current version of RTools sets the path to c:\Rtools\bin no matter what you choose when you install RTools. I believe this is done in Renviron.site in the etc folder of your R distribution. You could edit this file and give it the correct path. (Alternatively, if the correct version of Rtools is already in your path (ie you elected to modify the system path when you installed it) then you might get this to work by simply commenting-out (put a # in front of) the PATH= statement in Renviron.site.

Does anyone know where to report this as a possible bug in the installation for RTools?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! My system has some issues to modify the Renviron.site. But I think this is on the track of a solution. Also aye on the question about bug or issue reporting of RTools.